# How to delete the active scene from all the scene list unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to make a scene manager script and to random change scene on trigger enter 2D. But I don't want to load the active scene. I managed to get all the scenes on a list, but i don't know how to remove the active one from the list. I use this code:

```
    int sceneCount = SceneManager.sceneCountInBuildSettings;
    Debug.Log("sceneCount:  " + sceneCount);
    string[] scenes = new string[sceneCount];
    for (int i = 0; i < sceneCount; i++)
    {
        scenes[i] = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(SceneUtility.GetScenePathByBuildIndex(i));

        scenes[i].Remove(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex);

        Debug.Log(scenes[i]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of adding all scenes and then removing,a better approach would be that before adding the scene to the array you could check if the index is the same:

```
if(i != SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex)
        {
            scenes[i] = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(SceneUtility.GetScenePathByBuildIndex(i));
        }
```

But now there is a small issue the array element of that index is null, you could possible just check if the element is null and don't instantiate it but then we may get some code more complex that it should be...

Instead of an array everything will be easier using a **List**, in summary List are like arrays but you don't need to specify the size.

```
List<string> scenes = new List<string>();
    for (int i = 0; i < sceneCount; i++)
    {
        if(i != SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex)
        {
            scenes.Add(System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(SceneUtility.GetScenePathByBuildIndex(i)));
        }
    }
```

Finally, you want to know if everything is ok, so we access each element of the List:

```
//Acces each element of the list
    for(int i = 0; i < scenes.Count; i++)
    {
        Debug.Log(scenes[i]);
    }
```

You can read more of the [List class here](https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/csharp/csharp-list).

Comment: Works great for what I want. Thank's you !